# Rails Mountable Engine "update" method inaccessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, rails-engines

I have a project with a mounted engine within it. So far, everything works as I expect except "update" functionality.  The engine controller was created via scaffold, and everything looks as I expect it to.  Index, Show, Edit, Delete all work as expected, as do the associated before and after filter actions.

However, Update throws the following exception:

screen:

```
NoMethodError in MeetmeManagerPlugin::ConferenceRoomsController#update

private method `update' called for #<MeetmeManagerPlugin::ConferenceRoom:0x007fe8ac24a080>
```

console:

```
NoMethodError (private method `update' called for #<MeetmeManagerPlugin::ConferenceRoom:0x007fe8ac24a080>):
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:404:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
  /Volumes/MacTheCrypt 1/Project Work/jkl5_projects/meetme_manager_plugin/app/controllers/meetme_manager_plugin/conference_rooms_controller.rb:57:in `update'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
```

The actual code in the controller looks like:

```
def update
  if @conference_room.update(conference_room_params)
    redirect_to @conference_room, notice: 'Conference room was successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: 'edit'
  end
end
```

What it is choking on is the "@conference_room.update(conference_room_params)".

A fair bit of web searching hasn't yet put any light on this, so I figured someone here might have a suggestion.  Thanks in advance, and let me know if you need anything further from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The work around for this problem is to use "update_attributes" and not "update":

```
def update
  if @conference_room.update_attributes(conference_room_params)
    redirect_to @conference_room, notice: 'Conference room was successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: 'edit'
  end
end # def update
```

Works just fine this way. So while I'm still not sure why the other approach is borken, given it's scaffold code, this does allow program execution to complete without error.